# mapView with multiple pins

Tags: ios, annotations

I tried all day to get a mapView with multiple pins running.
I followed a tutorial

http://www.verious.com/article/creating-multiple-annotations-or-pins-in-a-map-view/

and it seemed quite fine. The problem is at the
very end. The line

```
[self.myMapView addAnnotations:locations];
```

gets me an error that myMapView is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Change `self.myMapView` with `self.[the name you have given to your mapview]`. For example if you declared your mapView as greateMapview put `self.greateMapview`.

Do not forget to import the MapKit framework.

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer. Of course I have imported the MapKit. I have given it the name myMapView. But in the line self.myMapView add location:locations the myMapView is not recognized anymore. I guess the code format has changed.

Comment: Check how you declared the mapview